# Handle clicks on Image in ImageViewer (Codenameone)

Tags: java, image, frameworks, codenameone, image-viewer

We try to make an image clickable for some time within the Image Viewer.
In my view, there is no listener for it?

We have a gallery of images. After clicking on an image that is to be opened in a separate window.

In another thread we found the opportunity to put any image on a button. For this we need to restructure our gallery, what we want to avoid

Here is the code for opening the image. This works well so far:

```
Form picture = (Form) createContainer(res, "ImageViewer");
beforeImageViewer(picture, currentObjektModel);
picture.showBack();
postImageViewer(picture, iv.getImageList().getItemAt(iv.getImageList().getSelectedIndex()));
```

Comment: What do the `beforeImageViewer()` and `postImageViewer()` comprise?

Comment: Thx diamond,
we will solve it differently now.
a picture for the detail page and a button with "more pictures .." what image viewer opens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with doing that is that image viewer handles pointer events for swipe/pan which you rely on. You can use `ScaleImageButton` for most cases but since you need swiping this is probably not an option.

You can derive image viewer and override `pointerPressed` & `pointerReleased`.

If pressed is called with released almost immediately after and the distance between the two x/y coordinates (from the pressed/released) is small then that's probably a click.

Comment: the solution with pointers sounds very interesting.
now that the requirements have changed, we can solve it differently.
a picture for the detail page and a button with "more pictures .." what image viewer opens.
Thanks for your help